Scala Test Failing Assertion
I created a sample dataset which I later compare with the results of a function in the Main app.
The sample looks like this:
val expected_ds_t1 = Seq(
  driveAggMonthly(1, 1),
  driveAggMonthly(2, 2),
  driveAggMonthly(3, 1)
).toDS().as[driveAggMonthly]

Where the driveAggMonthly class looks like:
case class driveAggMonthly(Month: Int,
                            numberOfDrives: BigInt)

Now, when I run printSchema() on expected_ds_t1, it looks like :
root
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- numberOfDrives: bigInt (nullable = true)

The dataset I am comparing with this one, is created as follows:
    val source_ds = Seq(
      Drive(48, 0, "abc", "def", "2017-01-01"),
      Drive(94, 0, "ghi", "hkl", "2017-02-01"),
      Drive(82, 0, "mno", "pqr", "2017-02-05"),
      Drive(21, 0, "stu", "vwx", "2017-03-01")
    ).toDS().as[Drive]

    val result_ds_t1: Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = nr_drives_by_month(source_ds: Dataset[Drive])

  def nr_drives_by_month(input_ds: Dataset[Drive]): Dataset[driveAggMonthly] = {
    input_ds
      .groupBy(month(to_date(col("date"))).as("Month"))
      .agg(count(col("driveId")).as[Long].as("numberOfDrives"))
      .as[driveAggMonthly]
  }

The resulting schema looks like:
root
 |-- Month: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- numberOfDrives: bigInt (nullable = true)

Now when I run the following assert:
assert(result_ds_t2 === expected_ds_t2)

I get the following error message:
[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint] did not equal [Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: assignment.MainTest$$anonfun$1 at (MainTest.scala:44)
Expected :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
Actual   :[Month: int, numberOfDrives: bigint]
<Click to see difference>

Even though I know both the schema and the data are the same.
explanation is stated above

You have created a duplicate question Scalatest comparing two identical Datasets failing, if they are actually different in some way - please explain how, given you are now past NPE's you should also accept answers that were correct or at least add a solution of your own to the first question you asked.
